# Is there a way to broadcast account addresses to other nodes in a private blockchain?

Tags: transactions, accounts, private-blockchain, nodes

I am running a private blockchain and have a couple of geth nodes which are connected. I have multiple accounts on both the nodes. From node 1, through the **admin.peers** command, I can get the enode URL of node 2. With this enode URL(including IP address and port #), is it possible to retrieve the list of accounts on node 2 from the geth instance on node 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, by default you cannot see what accounts are controlled by other nodes on the network. However, you can get the IP address of your peers with

`admin.peers[index].network.remoteAddress`

If the other node has remote RPC enabled (start geth with the `--rpc --rpcaddr *` flags), however, it is possible to get their list of accounts.

You can either use nodeJS and use the remote host as a web3 provider, or you can fetch the list manually using

`curl -X POST -d '{"method":"eth_accounts"}' remoteIP:8545`

Answer (score 4):

You need to know the address of the account you want to transfer to on node 2. Given the blockchain is private and you own both nodes, you should therefore know the addresses of the accounts on both.

On node 2, assuming that you're running Geth, you can run:

- `geth accounts list` from the CLI, or
- `eth.accounts` from within Geth's console

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I wanted to know whether I could get the list of accounts on node 2 from the geth instance on node 1.

Answer (score 3):

Accounts are not bounded to a node in any way. Like Richard said, you have useful functions like

- `geth accounts list` from the CLI, or
- `eth.accounts` from within Geth's console

to check what accounts a node can see. A node can actually see accounts if they are stored inside keystore folder (i.e. in windows %APPDATA%\Ethereum\keystore)